# Solving $x^3 + x^2 - 4 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does anyone know how to solve

$$
x^3 + x^2 - 4 = 0
$$

analytically? That is, without using numerical methods to attain an approximate solution.

Comment: If you're up for a lot of algebraic computations, there's always [Cardano's formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano's_Formula)

Comment: I often downvote PSQ's, but not this one.  Most students are never taught this and might not know where else to look.  If you haven't seen this done before, it would be really hard to figure out the formula.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 3):

By the rational root test, this equation doesn't have any rational roots.

So you have to use the general method for solving [cubic equations.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method)

Answer (score 2):

Using [Cardano's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano.27s_method) method (and a cas to do the calculations):

we start with

$$x^3+x^2-4=0 \tag{1}$$

and substitute 
$$x=t-{{1}\over{3}} \tag{2}$$
to get
$$t^3-{{t}\over{3}}-{{106}\over{27}}=0 \tag{3}$$

It is always possible to find a substitution $x=t+a$ such that the coefficient of $x^2$ vanishes.

Now we set 
$$t=v+u \tag{4}$$
and get

$$v^3+{{\left(v+u\right)\,\left(9\,u\,v-1\right)}\over{3}}+u^3-{{106
 }\over{27}}=0 \tag{5}$$

We impose the additional condition that 
$$u\,v={{1}\over{9}}  \tag{6}$$

and get

$$v^3+u^3={{106}\over{27}} \tag{7}$$

and

$$u^3\,v^3={{1}\over{729}} \tag{8}$$

So $u^3$ and $v^3$ are the solution of the quadratic equation

$$z^2-{{106\,z}\over{27}}+{{1}\over{729}}=0 \tag{9}$$

This equation has the solutions

$$\left \{-{{6\,\sqrt{78}-53}\over{27}} , {{6\,\sqrt{78}+53
 }\over{27}} \right \} \tag{10}$$

$u$ and $v$ are interchangeable, we set

$$u^3=-{{6\,\sqrt{78}-53}\over{27}} \tag{11}$$
$$v^3={{6\,\sqrt{78}+53
 }\over{27}} \tag{12}$$

Both values have a real cubic root. We can set

$$u=\sqrt[3]{-{{6\,\sqrt{78}-53}\over{27}}} \tag{13}$$
$$v=\sqrt[3]{{{6\,\sqrt{78}+53
 }\over{27}}} \tag{14}$$

because these solution pair satisfies $(1)$.

From this we get 
$$x=\sqrt[3]{-{{6\,\sqrt{78}-53}\over{27}}} + \sqrt[3]{{{6\,\sqrt{78}+53
 }\over{27}}} +1/3  \tag{15}$$

$1$ has three roots in $\mathbb{C}$:
$$\left \{ 1 , {{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}} , -{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}} \right \} \tag{16}$$
So the two other soltuions we construct from

$$u=(\sqrt[3]{-{{6\,\sqrt{78}-53}\over{27}}}) ({{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}) \tag{17}$$
$$v=(\sqrt[3]{{{6\,\sqrt{78}+53
 }\over{27}}}) (-{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}})  \tag{18}$$

and

$$u=(\sqrt[3]{-{{6\,\sqrt{78}-53}\over{27}}}) (-{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}) \tag{19}$$
$$v=(\sqrt[3]{{{6\,\sqrt{78}+53
 }\over{27}}}) ({{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}) \tag{20}$$

in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general formula to write solutions of any cubic equation. Here is your solution (computed with wolfram alpha): 
$$ x = \frac{-1+\sqrt[3]{53-6 \sqrt{78}}+\sqrt[3]{53+6 \sqrt{78}}}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) might prove itself useful... (See also the *Special cases* section below, if necessary).